# Фабрика класса в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Объясните,пожалуйста, простым языком, для чего в C# служит фабрика класса

Вот на этом примере из книги Шилдта:

```
// Использовать фабрику класса. 
using System; 

class MyClass { 
    int a, b; // закрытые члены класса 

    // Создать фабрику для класса MyClass. 
    public MyClass Factory(int i, int j) { 
        MyClass t = new MyClass(); 
        t.a = i; 
        t.b = j; 
        return t; // возвратить объект 
    } 

    public void Show() { 
        Console.WriteLine("а и b: " + a + " " + b); 
    } 
} 

class MakeObjects { 
    static void Main() { 
        MyClass ob = new MyClass (); 
        int i, j; 

        // Сформировать объекты, используя фабрику класса. 
        for(i=0, j=10; i < 10; i++, j—) { 
            MyClass anotherOb = ob.Factory(i, j); // создать объект 
            anotherOb.Show(); 
        } 
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: для того же, для чего и в любом другом языке программирования. Это обьясняется в любом курме по ООП. Будте добры, пройти такой курс. Не зря же люди 5 лет учатся в универе на программиста.

Comment: кстати, код в примере из вопроса - это не фабрика (не factory method)

Comment: @metalurgus "Не зря же люди 5 лет учатся в универе на программиста." -- лол. Я получил далекооо не самое худшее образование в питерском Политехе по специальности "Программное обеспечение". Так вот про паттерны нам не рассказывали. Я это к тому, что программирование одним ООП не заканчивается и для изучения в универе есть более фундаментальные вещи. Это не техучилище.

Comment: @PashaPash во-первых, фабрика и фабричный метод -- это разные вещи. Во-вторых, в примере таки фабрика. Правда, не абстрактная. И наименования класса и метода дурацкие.

Comment: @andreycha с таким широким подходом - любой метод, в котором есть слово new - это фабрика. я имел ввиду, что паттерн factory method, как и любой паттерн - это, прежде всего, стандартное решение конкретной проблемы проектирования. Если написан код, который *похож* (наличием слова *new* и наличием метода), но самой проблемы, которую решает паттерн при этом нет - то это не пример применения паттерна, а просто кусок кода. В примере из поста проблемы, которую решает фабрика (любая - абстрактная или fm), нет и не было изначально - значит это просто код ради кода.

Comment: @andreycha собственно поэтому вопрос у топикастера и возник. "вот фабрика классов (или как оно там переведено), вот так реализуется". Проблемы, которую решает паттерн, не было - и естественный вопрос - а зачем вообще паттерн? И ответ на него, IMHO, - это у вас не паттерн :)

Answer (score 7):

Это не полноценный ответ, я просто приведу несколько примеров, в которых из этого можно извлечь пользу. Настоящий ответ наверняка кто-нибудь даст позже; пошу прощения за огрехи в синтаксисе, если таковые будут

Например, если у нас есть такой кусок кода:

```
public void runProcess()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.Run('where cmd');
}
```

То в нем не только намертво прибит конкретный класс, но и сам экземпляр этого класса генерируется на лету, а значит, `runProcess()` нельзя полноценно протестировать - при попытках его протестировать придется оглядываться на работспособность `Process`, и неработоспособность `Process` завалит два теста разом. Фабрика позволяет разрешить эту жесткую зависимость даже с сохранением точного используемого класса:

```
class ProcessFactory {
    public Process CreateProcess()
    {
        return new Process();
    }
}

class ProcessRunner {
    private ProcessFactory processFactory;
    public ProcessRunner(ProcessFactory processFactory)
    {
        this.processFactory = processFactory;
    }
    public void runProcess()
    {
        Process process = processFactory.CreateProcess();
        process.Run('where cmd');
    }
}
```

В этом случае сама генерация объекта выносится за пределы класса, и можно сделать мок (подделку) `ProcessFactory`, которая всегда будет возвращать экземпляр, работающий так, будто он и впрямь успешно запускает процесс. Саму `ProcessFactory` при том тестировать не нужно - там всего одна однозначная строчка.

Кроме того, фабрика отделяет создание экземпляра класса от места вызова. Это позволяет реализовать дополнительный функционал, например, шаблоны Builder, Flyweight:

```
 class RequestFactory {
     public Request CreateRequest(URL url)
     {
          Request request = new Request;
          request.SetAsync(true);
          request.SetUrl(url);
          if (NetworkManager.GetNetworkQuality() < 0.5) {
              request.SetTimeout(500);
          } else {
              request.SetTimeout(100);
          }
          request.SetRetries(5);
          request.AddHeader('User-Agent', 'My incredible software');
          return request;
     }
 }
```

В данном примере внешний код может больше не заботиться об инициализации экземпляра класса, потому что фабрика совмещает в себе шаблон Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Это применяется когда есть наследники имеющий схожий функционал, но по некоторым причинам создание этих наследников через конструктор не целесообразно.

Например `WebRequest` имеет статический метод `Create`, который в зависимости от протокола переданного `Uri` создает соответствующий класс, http -`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, ftp - `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` и т. д.

Тоже про `System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm`.